# Focus on/switch to tab in which the content script is running in

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script that – at a certain time – loads a new website by adjusting `window.location.href` accordingly.

Before loading the new URL, I would like to switch to the tab automatically in which the content script is running in.

I guess I can use [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) to activate the tab, but how can I get the correct `tabId`?

```
var updateProperties = {"active": true};
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, updateProperties, function(tab){ });
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Since chrome.tabs [is not available](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in a content script, simply send a message to your background/event page script where you can use [sender.tab.id in onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) listener.

Comment: Thx. I'm currently not using a background/event page but I will include it and try your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved my problem (Thanks for the advice, xOxxOm):

In the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  // Set focus on window
  chrome.windows.update(sender.tab.windowId, {"focused": true}, function(window){ });
  // Set focus on tab
  chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {"active": true}, function(tab){ });
});
```

In the content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Do something");
```